# how to make Google search using c++ program

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am wondering and almost searched everywhere on the web but couldn't find anything helpful. I am quite a beginner with c++. Is there any possible way to make a Web search when I type a word in console on program runtime, it should go to google.com and fetch the meaning of that word to my .txt file or directly on my console? Basically, I am trying to implement a  dictionary (offline+Online) using c++ and linked lists/trees.

Any sort of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify, do you want your program to search the web or do you what a program that will invoke Chrome and send commands to Chrome?

Comment: [First search result for "Google search API"](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).

Comment: Remember that you have to use Google's services via their interfaces and adhere to their terms of service.  [Automatically generating a query](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/automated-queries) must be done via their API.  If you do not, you'll find that you'll get a captcha instead of a result after their system identifies the traffic pattern.  It's also neither [free nor unlimited](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview#pricing).

Comment: you need to use the REST API google provides. The most used language for this is js, but you can do it in C++ with a library.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I want to send commands to Google Chrome

Answer (score 5):

There is a couple of steps to this that you may need to do before you even start writing the C++ code.

Note: C++ is probably not the easiest language to do this in.

1. You will need a google account.
   Go to the [website and sign up](https://developers.google.com/u/me?) (free)
2. You will need to get an API Key
   Go to the [website and generate](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/introduction#identify_your_application_to_google_with_api_key) (free)
3. You will need to know the [REST command to generate output](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list).
   Here the easiest thing to do is to use CURL to test your REST query (or use a tool like [PostMan](https://www.postman.com/)). Though their website provides a simple starting point to test parameters.
4. Once you have the rest command working on the command line. Convert this to C code using the [libcurl API](https://curl.se/libcurl/).
5. You will need to parse the returned value.
   The returned value is JSON you will need to either parse this manually or use an [existing library](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). There are several out there. I hear [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) is good I prefer [ThorsSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer) but I wrote that so I am [biased](https://lokiastari.com/Json/Performance.linux.html).

---

Making a dictionary (non commercial).
Its probably simpler to use the [MERRIAM-WEBSTER'S](https://dictionaryapi.com/) API rather than googles.

Step 1: Register to get an API Key
https://dictionaryapi.com/register/index

Step 2: Get The API Key

- Once you have filled out the form.
- And confirmed your e-mail
- And Logged into [dictionaryapi.com](https://dictionaryapi.com/sign-in)
- Go to your [keys page](https://dictionaryapi.com/account/my-keys)

Step 3: Verify you can get information from the command line

- [Documentation here](https://dictionaryapi.com/products/api-collegiate-dictionary)

Note: My key is not going to work for you (I deleted it). You will have to create and use your own.

```
curl https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/voluminous?key=568e93fa-c06f-4f96-bf12-948cf301a03f
```

Step 4: Convert the command line into C code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <curl/curl.h>

extern "C" size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *dataFromServerVoid)
{
    std::string& dataFromServer = *(reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(dataFromServerVoid));

    dataFromServer.append(ptr, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Fail: Read Instructions\n";
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Dictionary:\n"
              << "    Getting: " << argv[1] << "\n";

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        static const std::string apiKey = "?key=568e93fa-c06f-4f96-bf12-948cf301a03f";
        static const std::string urlBase = "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/";

        const std::string url = urlBase + argv[1] + apiKey;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

        // The default action is to print any data returned
        // to the standard output. But we are going to need to
        // processes that data so adding some functions
        // and data to capture the output.
        std::string dataFromServer;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &dataFromServer);

        // Get the data from the server.    
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        // If the call worked we can print out
        // what we retrieved.
        if (res == CURLE_OK) {
            std::cout << "    Got: >" << dataFromServer << "<\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Step 5: Build and verify it works.

```
> g++ -std=c++17 dict.cpp -lcurl
> ./a.out bootstrap
```

We get:

```
Dictionary:
    Getting: bootstrap
    Got: >[{"meta":{"id":"bootstrap:1","uuid":"9c960ec2-a3ce-4f09-a7ba-a4972036314a","sort":"020350800","src":"collegiate","section":"alpha","stems":["bootstrap","bootstraps"],"offensive":false},"hom":1,"hwi":{"hw":"boot*strap","prs":[{"mw":"\u02c8b\u00fct-\u02ccstrap","sound":{"audio":"bootst01","ref":"c","stat":"1"}}]},"fl":"noun","def":[{"sseq":[[["sense",{"sn":"1","dt":[["text","{bc}a looped strap sewed at the side or the rear top of a boot to help in pulling it on"]]}]],[["sense",{"sn":"2","ins":[{"if":"boot*straps","spl":"plural"}],"dt":[["text","{bc}unaided efforts "],["uns",[[["text","often used in the phrase {it}by one\u0027s own bootstraps{\/it}"]]]]]}]]]}],"date":"1875{ds||1||}","shortdef":["a looped strap sewed at the side or the rear top of a boot to help in pulling it on","unaided efforts \u2014often used in the phrase by one\u0027s own bootstraps"]},{"meta":{"id":"bootstrap:2","uuid":"59331df1-c1fd-44ff-bd8d-73d471ad6819","sort":"020350900","src":"collegiate","section":"alpha","stems":["bootstrap"],"offensive":false},"hom":2,"hwi":{"hw":"bootstrap"},"fl":"adjective","def":[{"sseq":[[["sense",{"sn":"1","dt":[["text","{bc}designed to function independently of outside direction {bc}capable of using one internal function or process to control another "],["vis",[{"t":"a {wi}bootstrap{\/wi} operation to load a computer"}]]]}]],[["sense",{"sn":"2","dt":[["text","{bc}carried out with minimum resources or advantages "],["vis",[{"t":"{wi}bootstrap{\/wi} efforts"}]]]}]]]}],"date":"1926{ds||1||}","shortdef":["designed to function independently of outside direction : capable of using one internal function or process to control another","carried out with minimum resources or advantages"]},{"meta":{"id":"bootstrap:3","uuid":"257edd7e-c31a-453a-a15b-e1d022c70d96","sort":"020351000","src":"collegiate","section":"alpha","stems":["bootstrap","bootstrapped","bootstrapper","bootstrappers","bootstrapping","bootstraps"],"offensive":false},"hom":3,"hwi":{"hw":"bootstrap"},"fl":"verb","ins":[{"if":"boot*strapped"},{"if":"boot*strap*ping"}],"def":[{"vd":"transitive verb","sseq":[[["sense",{"dt":[["text","{bc}to promote or develop by initiative and effort with little or no assistance "],["vis",[{"t":"{it}bootstrapped{\/it} herself to the top"},{"t":"\u2026 turns out to be pretty talented at identifying and {wi}bootstrapping{\/wi} promising creative endeavors.","aq":{"auth":"Harry McCracken"}}]]]}]]]}],"uros":[{"ure":"boot*strap*per","fl":"noun"}],"date":"1951","shortdef":["to promote or develop by initiative and effort with little or no assistance"]}]<
```

Step 6: Extract the data from the JSON

I am going to use ThorsSerializer to get the data. This allows de-serialization of JSON directly into C++ objects without having to parse and interpret any intermediate objects. This makes it really usefull for stable web interfaces (like most REST interfaces).

Step 6a: Install ThorsSerializer

```
> brew install thors-serializer
```

A useful tip here. To visualize and quickly see the JSON there is a great command line tool `jq`. if you stream JSON to this the default action is simply to prity print the JSON (though it has a lot more power)

```
> brew install jq
> echo "<JSON TEXT>" | jq
```

Step 6b: Build Definition of what you want:

Looking at the definition of JSON we only need one bit of data "shortdef" which is an array of strings inside a definition object.

```
// So simply declare an object like the JSON declaraition.
// You can ignore any parts of the JSON you don't want.
struct Definition
{
    std::vector<std::string>   shortdef;
};

// Now tell the ThorsSerializer the bits it needs to understand.
// The library already knows how to handle all the standard types.
// So no extra declarations needed for std::vector.
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Definition, shortdef);
```

Step 6C: Write code to extract data from JSON.

```
        using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonImporter;

        std::stringstream           dataFromServerStream(dataFromServer);
        std::vector<Definition>     definition;

        // ThorsSerializer works for any type of stream.
        // Files are supported natively and its not hard
        // to wrap sockets as a stream if you want to.
        // In this case I have kept it simple.
        dataFromServerStream >> jsonImporter(definition);
```

Step 6c: Put it all together:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <curl/curl.h>
#include "ThorSerialize/Traits.h"
#include "ThorSerialize/JsonThor.h"

extern "C" size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *dataFromServerVoid)
{
    std::string& dataFromServer = *(reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(dataFromServerVoid));

    dataFromServer.append(ptr, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

struct Definition
{
    std::vector<std::string>   shortdef;
};
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Definition, shortdef);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Fail: Read Instructions\n";
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Dictionary:\n"
              << "Getting: " << argv[1] << "\n";

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        static const std::string apiKey = "?key=568e93fa-c06f-4f96-bf12-948cf301a03f";
        static const std::string urlBase = "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/";

        const std::string url = urlBase + argv[1] + apiKey;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());


        std::string dataFromServer;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &dataFromServer);

        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        if (res == CURLE_OK) {
            using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonImporter;

            std::stringstream           dataFromServerStream(dataFromServer);
            std::vector<Definition>     definition;

            dataFromServerStream >> jsonImporter(std::move(definition));
            for(auto def: definition[0].shortdef) {
                std::cout << "    " << def << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Step 7: Build

```
g++ -std=c++17 main2.cpp -lcurl -lThorSerialize17 -lThorsLogging17
> ./a.out bootstrap
```

We get:

```
Dictionary:
Getting: bootstrap
    a looped strap sewed at the side or the rear top of a boot to help in pulling it on
    unaided efforts —often used in the phrase by one's own bootstraps
```

---

Just as a comparison.
The same code in Javascript. Now my javascript is not good. But this code is still tighter and more readable. So this shows that C++ is not the best language to do this as a beginner.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const apiKey = "?key=568e93fa-c06f-4f96-bf12-948cf301a03f";
const urlBase = "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/";

const url = urlBase + process.argv[2] + apiKey;

fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((definition) => {
        for(var item in definition[0].shortdef) {
            console.log(definition[0].shortdef[item]);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => { throw err });
```

To run this:

```
> node dict.js bootstrap
```

But saying that. If you find an appropriate library this code can be just as concise as the Javascript. But you need an appropriate library (which may be difficult and hard to find/build and install). All of which are made easy with javascript.

Example of simple version:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "ThorSerialize/Traits.h"
#include "ThorSerialize/JsonThor.h"
#include "ThorSocketStream/ThorsSimpleStream.h"


struct Definition
{
    std::vector<std::string>    shortdef;
};
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(Definition, date, shortdef);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using ThorsAnvil::Stream::IThorSimpleStream;
    using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonImporter;

    static const std::string apiKey = "?key=key=568e93fa-c06f-4f96-bf12-948cf301a03f";
    static const std::string urlBase = "https://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v3/references/collegiate/json/";

    const std::string url = urlBase + argv[1] + apiKey;
    IThorSimpleStream stream(url);

    std::vector<Definition> dataFromServer;
    stream >> jsonImporter(dataFromServer)

    for(auto const& def: dataFromServer[0].shortdef) {
        std::cout << "    " << data << "\n";
    }
}
```

But getting the SimpleStream library may take some work to build.

Comment: This is a great answer, even if it only demonstrates the scale of what the poster was originally asking for. I suspect they'd be better off considering a scripting language like python for this task.

Comment: @Fibbs Add a section for Javascript (I don't like python).

Comment: FWIW - The use of a library like yhirose's excellent httplib might be easier than interfacing with libcurl directly.  But I'm not sure it does much to reduce the total amount of required effort.  It can be done, I've used this library in conjunction with json parsers to consume a variety of APIs...  https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib

Comment: @psyklopz Sure thats a valid step up. But it could be simpler. I also have a library that simplifies the socket connection into a stream [ThorsStream](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsStream/blob/master/doc/example1.md). It treats a socket connection as a stream for easy processing. Not as versitile as cpp-httplite but its all you need for something as simple as this. See the last example.

Comment: @psyklopz I take that back. That library from the client side looks nice and easy to use.

Comment: @MartinYork I'm impressed with your library as well.  I've bookmarked it, I might get the chance to use it someday.

Comment: @MartinYork Thanks for your answer. Looks like more to do with the technical settings rather than just writing code.

Comment: @AlexG Its more to with other people proving a service that you want to use and making sure that developers don't abuse the service. Putting a service on the internet is not free and if abused can cost you a lot of money. Making sure that people don't abuse the service by forcing them to register and get keys so you can track them (and cut them off when they abuse you) is the minimum thing people need to do for their own sanity.

Comment: Hello @MartinYork! Maybe I am not ready to hear that the developers' team of StackOverflow degrade and discourage developers to share their thoughts. Is it like that?

Comment: @AlexG I think you missed the point. Google/Webster/Facebook anybody that runs an online service is providing you a tool. It costs them money to provide that tool, and you are not going to pay for it. To make sure that developers don't abuse their services, these service providers make you register and thus act responsibly because you are identified in each request you make (via the key or secret).